# flipperzero ufbt launch gives me errors. --gc-sections requires a defined symbol root specified by -e or -u

Tags: flipper

I'm using Visual Code (Version 1.87.0) to create a basic hello world app.  When I run ufbt launch I get the following error. I have tried UFBT update to make sure I have the latest stable version.  I have tried googling with no clear answer or direction.

ld.exe: --gc-sections requires a defined symbol root specified by -e or -u

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

> c:/users/knlkl/.ufbt/toolchain/x86_64-windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: --gc-sections requires a defined symbol root specified by -e or -u
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> scons: *** [C:\Users\knlkl.ufbt\build\hello_world_d.elf] Error 1